# How to get interface level configuration from the "sh run" output in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can anyone help me how to get only interface configuration out of "sh run" output text file of a cisco Router/Switch configuration.

```
if not os.path.exists(Destpath):
        os.makedirs(Destpath)
        

    #time.sleep(10)

    File_SList=os.listdir(sourcepath)
    print(File_SList)

    interface_pattern=re.compile(r'(interface \S+)|( ip helper-address [\d.]+)')

    Number_File=0
    for X in File_SList:
      SpFile=X
      DFile=X
      print()
      print(SpFile)
      Number_File+=1
     
      with open(os.path.join(sourcepath,SpFile),"r") as file :
          
        Output=file.readlines()
        print("Check")
        
        helper_list=[]
               
        with open(os.path.join(Destpath,DFile),"a") as put : 

            for key in Output:
                      
               key=key.lower()
               if "interface" in key :
                    interface_name=key
                    print(key)
                    for key in Output:
                        if "!" not in key:
                            helper_list.append(key)
                        else :
                            break
                        for i in range(len(helper_list)) :
                            put.write(helper_list[i])
                    
                        helper_list=[]
```

From the below shared "sh run" output of a network switch how can we copy the configuration only related to interface (interface Port-channel1 , interface GigabitEthernet0/0, interface FastEthernet1/0/1, interface FastEthernet1/0/2, interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1.....) and save it to another file.

```
#
service tcp-keepalives-in
service tcp-keepalives-out
service timestamps debug datetime msec localtime show-timezone
service timestamps log datetime msec localtime show-timezone
service password-encryption
service sequence-numbers
service call-home
platform punt-keepalive disable-kernel-core
!
hostname Switch01
!
!
vrf definition Mgmt-vrf
 !
 address-family ipv4
 exit-address-family
 !
 address-family ipv6
 exit-address-family
!
logging userinfo
logging buffered 20000
!
stack-mac persistent timer 0
boot system bootflash:packages.conf
boot system flash:packages.conf
power redundancy-mode combined
power supply autoLC shutdown
power supply autoLC priority 1 2 5 6 7
!
ip arp gratuitous local
no ip gratuitous-arps
!
ip icmp rate-limit unreachable DF 200
no ip domain lookup
ip dhcp bootp ignore
!
no ip igmp snooping
login block-for 120 attempts 12 within 120
login quiet-mode access-class 109
login on-failure log
login on-success log
!
interface Port-channel1
 description  Po1
 switchport trunk native vlan 998
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10-12,20,100-107,110,301-401,556,601,602,691
 switchport trunk allowed vlan add 701-706,710,800,998,999
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface Port-channel2
 description Core Po2
 switchport trunk native vlan 999
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10-12,20,100-106,110,301-306,401,601,602,691
 switchport trunk allowed vlan add 701-706,710,800,998,999
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 vrf forwarding Mgmt-vrf
 no ip address
 shutdown
 negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 description VEDGE_1_UPLINK
 switchport access vlan 901
 switchport mode access
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 service-policy output QOS-OUTPUT-POLICY
!
interface FastEthernet1/0/1
 description **Connected to PC**
 switchport access vlan 111
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security aging time 2
 no logging event link-status
 speed 100
 duplex full
 priority-queue out
 mls qos trust dscp
 no snmp trap link-status
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 hold-queue 120 in
 hold-queue 200 out
 ip dhcp snooping trust
!
interface FastEthernet1/0/2
 description **Connected to Access Point****
 switchport access vlan 900
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security maximum 15
 switchport port-security
 switchport port-security aging time 2
 switchport port-security aging type inactivity
 ip access-group 100 in
 no logging event link-status
 srr-queue bandwidth shape 0 0 0 10
 queue-set 2

!

 priority-queue out
 no snmp trap link-status
 storm-control broadcast level pps 100 50
 storm-control multicast level pps 100 50
 storm-control action trap
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 service-policy input WIRELESS_IN
 ip dhcp snooping limit rate 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that should work for you:

```py
import os

sourcepath = "/your/path"
Destpath = "/your/other/path"

if not os.path.exists(Destpath):
    os.makedirs(Destpath)

# The code below has been unindented: otherwise this code will run only when Despath
# does not exist!

File_SList = os.listdir(sourcepath)
print(File_SList)

for X in File_SList:
    SpFile = X
    DFile = X
    print()
    print(SpFile)

    with open(os.path.join(sourcepath, SpFile), "r") as file:
        Output = file.readlines()
        print("Check")

    helper_list = []

    # Use 'w' to write, not 'a' to append because you would end up with the whole content
    # of your original file plus your custom extraction below in that same file.
    # I also unindented this `with` statement to make your code more readable.
    with open(os.path.join(Destpath, DFile), "w") as put:
        found_interface = False

        # Loop only once through the file!
        # (Notice there is no other `for key in Output` loop below)
        for key in Output:
            # Check if we have a start for a match, we assume no match by default
            if found_interface is False:
                key_lower = key.lower()
                if "interface" in key_lower:
                    interface_name = key
                    print(key)
                    found_interface = True

                    # If you want to keep the interface in lowercase, use `key_lower`
                    helper_list.append(key)
                # Important: while you are looping through each line, you do not want
                # to check for the end of a match (`!`) until you are effectively inside
                # an `interface` block, so don't run the rest of the logic in this loop
                continue

            # When `found_interface` is True, we know we want to capture any line until
            # we get an exclamation point
            if "!" not in key:
                helper_list.append(key)
            else:
                # Here, we have reached the end of the `interface` block. There is no
                # need to use range(len(...)), I have simplified your statement a bit.
                for line in helper_list:
                    put.write(line)

                helper_list = []
                found_interface = False
```

I have pointed out a few changes I made to your code in comments (and removed what's not relevant for clarity), but most importantly, the main logical error was located here in this second `for` loop:

```py
for key in Output:
    if "!" not in key:
```

The idea was clear: loop inside each `interface` block as long as you do not encounter an `!`. However, that means the code would look at each line more than once, which will get messy quickly! A better approach you want to go for is to loop only once through each line of the file and keep track of where you are.

In other words, in this approach, you mark your match (`interface`) and you keep appending a line until you find something you don't want (`!`). At that point, you "unmark" your match so that you don't append lines anymore. For each subsequent line, you then check to see if you are starting a new `interface` block.

Hope this helps! Cheers and welcome!

Comment: Thank you Sebastien for your help........